# Mongoose select fields from populated array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
// Users Collection

[{
  "id": "1",
  "email": "user1@mail.com",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "user": "2", // reference
      "nickname": "blub"
    },
    {
      "user": "3", // reference
      "nickname": "blub"
    },
  ],
  "otherfield": "anything"
}]
```

The `User` object contains an array `contacts` which basically represents a list of referenced `Users`. To allow storing additional data (like the `nickname`) per user I have an array of objects and not an array of ObjectIds.

Now I would like to get the contacts populated with specifying the fields to resolve (id and email for example). So the expected output is something like this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "email": "user1@mail.com",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "2",
        "email": "user2@mail.com",
        // without other fields 
      },
      "nickname": "blub"
    }
  ],
  "otherfield": "anything"
}
```

I have tried something like this

```
User.findById(id)
  .populate('contacts.user')
  .select('contacts.user.email')
```

But then my contacts array contains only empty objects.

Also if I try this:

```
User.findById(id).populate({
    path: 'contacts.user',
    select: 'email'
})
```

The outcome is just the parent user without any population:

```
{
  email: "user1@mail.com",
  id: "1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
User.findById(id).populate({
    path: 'contacts.user',
    select: 'email'
})
```

See **Populating multiple paths** of the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what I have overlooked in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) (thank you @Mikey)

```
Story.
  findOne({ title: /casino royale/i }).
  populate('author', 'name'). // only return the Persons name
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
    // prints "The author is Ian Fleming"

    console.log('The authors age is %s', story.author.age);
    // prints "The authors age is null'
  })
```